# Error Using the iif statement in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access

The completion_metric field from this query I made in MS ACCESS keeps giving me zero percent for all the records. I think something is wrong with my IIF statement. Also, how would can I populate a text box on a ms access form with this query. For text-boxes there seems to not be an option to let my record source be a query.

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(SUM(IIF (status='Completed',1,0)) / COUNT(Status),"percent") AS completion_metric
FROM   promis_lt 
GROUP BY Short_ID;
```

Comment: You need to multiply numerator by decimal constant `1.0` or use explicit type cast to decimal. Current code uses integer division, which will always show you zero (if this is a percentage of total). What about text box: you need to ask separate question

Comment: @astentx Nope, it's Access so / is floating point division, \ is integer division, regardless of data types of input. @OP Please provide sample data. Are you 100% sure the status field contains exactly completed, no hidden characters? Run `SELECT status, len(status) FROM promis_lt` and check if the length is as expected.

Comment: Also, never `SUM(x)/COUNT(x)`, always use `AVG` instead. Summing then dividing causes problems with overflows and accuracy that `AVG` doesn't have

Comment: Some sample data would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is integer division.  Instead:

```
SELECT FORMAT(AVG(IIF(status = 'Completed', 1.0 , 0)), "percent") AS completion_metric
FROM promis_lt
GROUP BY Short_ID
```

Comment: In the comments this solution is already suggested, and I already point out this is not the case, in Access / is always floating point and \ is integer division. Repeating a disputed comment is not a  useful answer